# show button when text is entered in pure HTML/LESS

Tags: html, less

I want a text field where i can insert text into and when i enter the text there should appear a button on the end of the textfield to clear the text. But I want this with only HTML/Less so without any JS.

As you can see in the code below I used the `display: none` attribute and i want to change the `display: none` to `display: block` after there is text entered in the input field.

code below:

```
                    <div class="input-field">
                    <input name="{{field.name}}" ng-model="field.value" type="text"/>

                    <button class="icon-assistant8 ci-cancel" type="reset">
                    </button>

                </div>
```

And this is the relevant Less file:

```
 .icon-assistant8 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.icon-assistant8:after {
    display: block;
}
```

Edit: After this example https://codepen.io/shidhincr/pen/ICLBD I know it is possible to do it with only HTML and CSS. I want to do that too but I can't get it to work and I do not know why.

Also I know I can do this with JS, I am just courious what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Since you're using angular, why not use Angular to do this?

Comment: You're already using JavaScript... What you're describing is *behaviour* and behaviour is altered via JavaScript.

Comment: @reinierkors I know I can do this with angular. But I just want to know if its possible to do it with only html and css. I have seen it work with html and css.

Comment: @AndréDion I linked to a page where they made it work with only html and css (in the edit) I know it is possible, but i am doing it wrong and thats basically my question. Why is it not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They key parts of [the example you've linked to](https://codepen.io/shidhincr/pen/ICLBD) that you haven't implemented in your own solution are

```
.search-box:not(:valid) ~ .close-icon {
    display: none;
}
```

```
<input type="text" name="focus" required class="search-box" placeholder="Enter search term" />
```

In order for `:not(:valid)` to match, you need the `required` attribute on the input. When the input is empty, it's considered not valid.

Here's a basic example

```css
input:not(:valid) ~ button { display: none; }
```

```html
<input type="text" required>
<button type="button">Foo</button>
```